# How to decode a scaled bitmap from URL efficiently

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am designing an app which has to deal with large number of bitmaps with huge size from server. There are ways to decode

Option 1:

1. Create a buffered inputstream from image url
2. Decode only the bounds
3. Create scale factor/sample size
4. Create a buffered inputstream (again since bitmapfactory closes the stream once decoding is complete)
5. Decode the bitmap

Option 2

1. Create a buffered inputstream from image url
2. Decode the bitmap in its original size
3. Use bitmap.createScaledBitmap to create desired size.

With option 1, we need to download the bitmap twice where as with 2, we have to explicitly recycle the original sized bitmap which will trigger garbage collection which is a CPU intense operation.

Are there any other methods that can achieve this efficiently?

Comment: Have the server return an appropriately sized bitmap is another option (and generally advised to reduce network transmission time/size - not everyone has good network speeds).

Comment: The server part is not under control. The app gets a url which has to be decoded.

Comment: `With option 1, we need to download the bitmap twice` .No. First you are not downloading a bitmap but a file. Probably a jpg file. Then if you decode the bounds only the header of the file will be downloaded. Not the whole file. The header is sufficient to decode the bounds. So go for option one.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 :

1. Download a file to the local file system
2. use Option 1

ps. Option 2 will overflow your memory eventually. Highly not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use inJustDecodeBounds. Set it to TRUE and load the file as it is.

The image won't be loaded into memory. But the outheight and outwidth properties of BitmapFactory.Options will contain the actual size params of the image specified. Calculate how much u want to subsample it. like 1/2 or 1/4 or 1/8 etc. and assign 2/4/8 etc. accordingly to the inSampleSize.

Now set inJustDecodeBounds to FALSE and call BitmapFactory.decodeFile() to load the image of the exact size as calculated above.

Comment: This is exactly option 1. But this will download the file twice.. once to decode bounds and one to decode the file

Comment: As of my knowledge the first "pass" will just download small part of the image - header, from which it will read the dimensions. The real decode will download entire image.So i don't thing it will download image twice.